# On click Show the posted data to another page

Tags: php, post, mysqli, cart

I am doing a project on CMS. There is a lot of data on a page including a `select` option. I want if any registered user clicks on `Select button` from *home* page (`index.php`) then the post will be showing to *liked posts page* (`likedpost.php`).

Similar to an *"Add To Cart"* function but not as complex. I just want if someone clicks `select` button, they can see their post to `likedposts` page and there will also be a `remove` button to not select.

A MySQLi form would work best.

Comment: A little too broad I think. You will what to try turning your question into code first, and if you get stuck, come back with that script as support to your question to show everyone what you have tried.

Comment: First of all every CMS have their own system of development. Please specify the CMS type. And for normal PHP web site you just need to put a link to your page where you want to go after clicking the link. You can place a <a>click me</a>. but please take time to write your question here and try some research and post your specific problem with code or CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send data to server via AJAX containing unique id of the post when user likes the post and save it in the Database. then in `likedposts` page you must define a realtime ajax request that queries for `likedposts` every second.

you can use `websocket` protocol instead of AJAX infinitive requests.